# What do I need for being able to migrate questions to other Stackexchange sites?

Tags: support

I've registered an account on Unix.SE but the website does not appear in the website selection for *Close as Offtopic*.

I doubt if it's a reputation issue, on http://Stackoverflow.com/ (8595 reputation) I see sites like programmers.stackexchange.com listed on which I've 103 reputation. On Unix.SE I've 111 rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migration paths for normal users don't exist on Ask Ubuntu - while they do exist on others. At this time a simple vote as off-topic then an accompanying moderator flag suggesting it be migrated will suffice.

Comment: Might this change in the future?

Comment: @Lekensteyn It's unlikely, we don't migrate nearly as much as the other sites - until our off-topic posts start to double or triple their current volume we probably won't get these paths.